# Ember.js: questions concerning controllers, 'this', 'content' and model structure

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scope

I am getting a little deeper into my first functional app and need to better understand what it going on in my controller.

Here I have a controller that handles the action when a user clicks on an 'Option'.  Looking at the `this` object raises a few questions:

1. What exactly is `this`?  I would expect it to be an instance of my Option model, but it is missing some properties (like "identity: 'model: Option'").
2. If `this` is an instance of my Option model, why is the 'model' property undefined? Why doesn't it just know that?
3. What is `this.content`?  It looks like some stuff is inside `content` (`id` and `isSuppressed`) and some is not (`this.isSelected`) - why is that?

**Disclaimer**: Though there aren't any presenting problems so far, there certainly could be errors in my ember app architecture.

**Screenshot debugging controller:**
[image: inspecting ember.js controller & data]

**Option Model & Controller**

```
App.Option = Ember.Object.extend({
    identity: 'model: Option',
    id: '',
    cost: '',
    isSelected: false,
    isSuppressed: false
});
App.OptionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        toggleOption: function() {
            this.set('isSelected', !this.get('isSelected'));
            var id = this.get('content.id');
            this.send('deselect', this.get('content.id'));
        }
    }
});
App.OptionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        deselect: function(exception) {
            var opts = this.rejectBy('id', exception)
            opts.setEach('isSuppressed', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For future readers: The confusion with `content` arose because my OptionController did not extend ObjectController.  After correcting this I was able to access all content via `get('property')` and `get('content.property')`.  See @kingpin2k in the selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where `this` is, if your in the controller it's the controller.  If your controller is an `ObjectController`/`ArrayController` it will proxy get/set calls down to the underlying model.  `content`/`model` are the same thing in the context of the controller.

The properties rarely live directly on the instance, usually they are hidden to discourage accessing the properties without using the getters/setters.

In your code above there is a good chance your `OptionController` should be extending `ObjectController`.  Unless the controller isn't backed by a model.  If you use `Ember.Controller.extend` then it won't proxy getters/setters down to the model, it will store, retrieve properties from the controller itself.